# magento 2 how to call a method from a block within a phtml

Tags: magento2

I have a block within a phtml file: the block is not associated with a controller.

```
echo $this->getLayout()
      ->createBlock("Top\CmsAndTemplatePages\Block\Cmspages")
      ->setTemplate("Top_CmsAndTemplatePages::categoryPages/rootblock.phtml")
      ->toHtml();
```

my question now is how do i call the methods of the block.

i.e within the class

**Top-> CmsAndTemplatePages->Block->Cmspages** is a method called

> **$this->_toHtml()**

how do i access this method from the phtml page

Comment: Please explain more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call the method of `Top\CmsAndTemplatePages\Block\Cmspages` then try to  below code:

```
  //Initiated   block class 
    $Cmspages = $block->getLayout()
          ->createBlock("Top\CmsAndTemplatePages\Block\Cmspages")

 //Call method of this class 
 $Cmspages->myTESTMethod();
```

Here **myTESTMethod** is a method of this class.

***And if you want to print the html output of this block then use***

```
<?= $Cmspages->toHtml() ?>
```

Comment: This works but you can only call public methods. I have a feeling `_toHtml` is a protected one.

Comment: OPPS, you can only class pUblic function not Protected and other